# Computing the shortest encoding for a transformation

Tags: semigroups, monoid

Here goes...

Let $n = 2^p$ for some $p \in \mathbb{N}$. Let $\mathcal{T}_n$ denote the set of all transformations on $\mathbb{Z}_n$ (viz. the [transformation monoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_semigroup)).

Pick $C$ to be an order $|\mathcal{T}_n|$ subset of the set of all binary strings that has the [prefix property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_code). Let $\phi$ be a bijection from $C$ to $\mathcal{T}_n$ ($\phi$ gives us a unique encoding for each transformation).

Now define an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $C^*$ (where $C^*$ is the set of all words on $C$) s.t.

$$a_1a_2\cdots a_q\sim b_1b_2\cdots b_r$$

iff

$$\phi(a_1)\phi(a_2)\cdots\phi(a_q)=\phi(b_1)\phi(b_2)\cdots\phi(b_r).$$

We'll define the "optimal length" of $x \in C$ as $\|x\| = \min \{|a| : a \sim x\}$ (where $|a|$ denotes the length of $a$ on the set of binary strings). I am interested in the quantity $\lambda = \sum_{x \in C} \|x\|$. This naturally leads to several questions:

1. How do I determine $\|x\|$?
2. How do I choose $C$ and $\phi$ such that $\lambda$ is minimized?
3. Is there a name for this problem and can anyone point me to any literature on it?

Thanks.

**Update:** I'm adding an example here to clarify what I'm attempting to communicate. Take $n = 2$. Then $\mathcal{T}_n = \{x, \neg x, T, F\}$. One choice for $C$ would be $\{(), (1), (01), (001)\}$. One choice for $\phi$ would be

$$\phi(()) = x$$
$$\phi((1)) = \neg x$$
$$\phi((01)) = T$$
$$\phi((0001)) = F$$

Then we have

$$\|\phi^{-1}(x)\| = \|()\| = 0,$$
$$\|\phi^{-1}(\neg x)\| = \|(1)\| = 1,$$
$$\|\phi^{-1}(T)\| = \|(01)\| = 2,$$

and because $(101) \sim (0001)$ (since $\phi((1))\phi((01)) = \neg T = F = \phi((0001))$)

$$\|\phi^{-1}(F)\| = \|0001\| = 3.$$

Therefore $\lambda = 6$, which I believe to be optimal for $n = 2$. (Before someone says something about $C$ not having the prefix property because the empty string is included, it is O.K. for my purposes in this instance specifically because it is mapped to the identity operator. Hopefully this is clear. Perhaps I should reword the bit about having the prefix property to include this.)

Comment: Why do you take $n = 2^p$? The problem makes sense for any $n$, doesn't it?

Comment: Are $a_1, \ldots, a_n$ and $b_1, \ldots, b_r$ elements of $C$? Then since $\phi$ is a *bijection* from $C$ to $\mathcal{T_n}$, one has $||x|| \leqslant 1$ for all $x \in C$. I suppose this is not what you wish. Please revise your question.

Comment: @J. E. Pin: Thank you, I've clarified what I meant by $|a|$ - the length of $a$ on the set of binary strings rather than the length of $a$ on $C^*$. I've taken $n = 2^p$ because that is the only case I'm interested in and there may be special results for that case that I don't know of, but more general results are certainly welcome.

Comment: I am still confused. Let $A$ be your binary alphabet. Is $\phi$  a map from $A$ to $\mathcal{T}_n$, extended to a monoid morphism from $A^*$ to $\mathcal{T}_n$? Then this morphism cannot be surjective, because you need at least three generators to generate $\mathcal{T}_n$.

Comment: @J. E. Pin: Thanks for sticking with me. I've had difficultly describing this problem clearly. I believe the best way to describe $\phi$ is as a bijection from $C$ to $\mathcal{T}_n$ as my intention is to ascribe a unique prefix code to each mapping in $\mathcal{T}_n$. My intention for $\|x\|$ is to find the shortest combination of prefix codes (by which I mean shortest binary string) $a_1a_2\cdots a_q$ where $a_i \in C$ such that $\phi(a_1)\phi(a_2)\cdots\phi(a_q) = \phi(x)$. Does that make any more sense?

Comment: It might make more sense if I add some background to the problem: I'm attempting to design an instruction set for a virtual machine. Each element of $\mathcal{T}_n$ is a potential instruction. Each instruction needs to be assigned a binary prefix code to be represented within a program. I'd like to find a way to minimize the average length of a program by choosing my instructions intelligently. Hopefully that is a little helpful.

Comment: @J.-E. Pin: Do you have any recommendations for how I might better format this question?

Comment: As I said, the main problem is that, for $n \geqslant 3$, you need at least three generators to generate $\mathcal{T}_n$. I suggest you give an example of what you wish for $\mathcal{T}_2$ and for $\mathcal{T}_3$.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin: Yes, I'm aware that I need at least 3 generators, I'm just failing to communicate my problem clearly :( I will add an example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26045/discussion-between-orby-and-j-e-pin).

Answer (score 1):

I still not fully understand your question, but here are some elements that may help you. First of all, for $n > 2$, you need at least three generators to generate $\mathcal{T_n}$. You could take for instance the following generators:
\begin{align}
a &= (2\ 3\ 4\ 5\ \dotsm \ n-1\ n\ 1) \quad \text{(a cyclic permutation)}\\
b &= (2\ 1\ 3\ 4\ \dotsm \ n-2\ n-1\ n) \quad \text{(the transposition exchanging $1$ and $2$)}\\
c &= (1\ 2\ 3\ 4\ \dotsm \ n-2\ n-1\ 1) \quad \text{(the identity on $\{1, \dotsm n-1\}$, but maps $n$ to $1$)}
\end{align}
Setting $A = \{a,b,c\}^*$, you now have a map $\varphi: A \to \mathcal{T_n}$, (defined, in the obvious way, by $\varphi(a) = a$, $\varphi(b) = b$, $\varphi(c) = c$). This map extends uniquely to a monoid morphism $\varphi: A^* \to \mathcal{T_n}$ by setting
$$
  \varphi(a_1a_2 \dotsm a_n) = \varphi(a_1) \varphi(a_2) \dotsm \varphi(a_n)
$$
Now, you may look for a subset $C$ on $A^*$ such that $\varphi$ induces a bijection from $C$ onto $\mathcal{T_n}$, and you may look for an optimal such $C$, in the sense that the $\sum_{x \in C} |x|$ is minimal.

From a theoretical point of view, you just consider the Cayley graph of the $A$-generated monoid $\mathcal{T_n}$ and look for geodesics from $1$ to any element of $\mathcal{T_n}$.

From a practical point of view, you may use the C-program [Semigroupe 2.01](http://www.liafa.univ-paris-diderot.fr/~jep/Logiciels/Semigroupe2.0/semigroupe2.html)
which computes this for you (up to $n = 8$). The following LaTeX output was generated by this program
\begin{align}
  &&1 &&2 &&3 \\
\hline
1 &&1 &&2 &&3 \\
a&&2 &&3 &&1 \\
b&&2 &&1 &&3 \\
c&&1 &&2 &&1 \\
aa&&3 &&1 &&2 \\
ab&&1 &&3 &&2 \\
ac&&2 &&1 &&1 \\
ba&&3 &&2 &&1 \\
ca&&2 &&3 &&2 \\
cb&&2 &&1 &&2 \\
aac&&1 &&1 &&2 \\
aca&&3 &&2 &&2 \\
acb&&1 &&2 &&2 \\
caa&&3 &&1 &&3 \\
cab&&1 &&3 &&1 \\
cba&&3 &&2 &&3 \\
aaca&&2 &&2 &&3 \\
aacb&&2 &&2 &&1 \\
acaa&&1 &&3 &&3 \\
acab&&3 &&1 &&1 \\
acba&&2 &&3 &&3 \\
caac&&1 &&1 &&1 \\
aacaa&&3 &&3 &&1 \\
aacab&&1 &&1 &&3 \\
aacba&&3 &&3 &&2 \\
caaca&&2 &&2 &&2 \\
caacaa&&3 &&3 &&3 \\
\hline
\end{align}
**Relations**
\begin{align}
bb &= 1 & bc &= ac & cc &= c & aaa &= 1 \\
aab &= ba & aba &= b & baa &= ab & bab &= aa \\
bac &= c & cac &= cb & acaac &= caac & caacb &= caaca \\
caacab &= caac 
\end{align}

**Warning**. The Cayley graph depends on the choice of the generators.

Comment: Thanks for sharing  your thoughts!